# How to get android background running process details

Tags: android, service, background-process

I want to list all background running processes and get details of those from one background service(Without UI). Details are as follows:

```
1. Name
2. Memory usage
3. Application related to process
4. Files they are accessing
5. Last modified time of files
```

I can get list of background running processes but how to get memory usage, Files they are accessing and Last modified time of files. **Is this possible to implement at API level?** Can anyone guide me How to do this? Can anybody give me idea or suggest useful link related to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Running Services UI uses [getRunningAppProcesses](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29), [getProcessMemoryInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getProcessMemoryInfo%28int%5B%5D%29), and [getRunningServices](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29).

Note that these only tell you about Java processes being managed by the high-level system; getRunningAppProcesses will not return information about low-level daemon processes.

The kernel has information about open files under /proc, but you can not get the information about another process unless you are running as root.

Also all currently running processes are under /proc, but please note that /proc is not a part of the Android SDK and there are no guarantees that your application will work across all devices or versions of the platform if using that.  /proc is a private implementation detail.

Answer (score 4):

With following line of code you can get currently running services list

```
ActivityManager localActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List RunningServiceInfoservices = localActivityManager.getRunningServices(100);
```

And from RunningServiceInfo you can get details for the process.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html

Comment: OK. Already I have done list of processes; I want to know  memory usage, Files they are accessing and Last modified time of files.

Comment: Once you know the PID, you can look them up in `/proc` and get all kinds of useful information there --- `/proc/$PID/status` is probably the one you're looking for. For file information, you may be out of luck, though, as you may not have permissions to access that information.