# How to get know when application's background services got block by other super-access application in android

Tags: android, service, background-process

My application performs `data synchronization` in background `service` which is **critical** task for application in order to work properly. now, application works fine & expected in some of devices having pure `Android` or near to pure `Android` ROM. e.g. **Google Nexus**, **Android One** & **Motorola devices**. but, some devices like **Redmi** having **MIUI** has inbuilt options for **blocking application's background processes**. which causes my application working not properly. So, I want to know "is there any way to find out my background processes are blocked? so that I can notify user to unblock it."

[here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226379/how-to-get-android-background-running-process-details?rq=1) a somewhat related question

here's some screenshot related to this.
[image]
[image]

Any suggestions or help are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

as i know, apps cannot get the info about whether or not in whitelist, but you can notify the user any more by :
Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setAction("miui.intent.action.OP_AUTO_START"); intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);